# Customize Emmet Sublime text 3

Tags: customization, sublimetext3, emmet

I would like to edit the "form" snippet made by Emmet, this is the current one :

```
<form action=""></form>
```

And I would like it to be :

```
<form method="" action=""></form>
```

[Emmet doc](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/) say that I must create a snippets.json file but I don't know where, I found nothing interesting in *C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User*

Am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: See https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#extensions-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to do this. Emmet has `form:get` and `form:post` shortcuts already, that create

```html
<form action="|" method="get">|</form>
```

and

```html
<form action="|" method="post">|</form>
```

elements, respectively, where the `|` indicates the two input fields. You move from the first to the second by hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Please reference the [cheat sheet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) for all of the abbreviations and shortcuts in Emmet.

Comment: Great ! I found this page earlier but it seems I read it too quickly.

Comment: @Seekme yeah, there's a lot there, and it's not all in alphabetical order, so some things are a little difficult to find.